# estimate of smallest eigenvalue of Schrodinger operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, schrodinger-operators

I am looking for references on  estimate of *first* nonzero Dirichlet eigenvalue for Schrodinger operator $-\Delta + V$, if sharp bounds exist, that would be better, here for simplicity, we can assume domain is in unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 2$. Here $V$ is assumed to be bounded from below and above. Thanks.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168882/estimate-the-smallest-eigenvalue-of-a-schrodinger-operator

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I have read the papers in that post, I am not asking about the exact question actually, the first eigenvalue is definitely positive here and the bounds I found are not very sharp. That is why I asked the same question but different purpose.